# How to install package using built-in osx python?

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I'm doing Alfred workflow. To execute it uses OSX built-in python interpreter `/usr/bin/python`. For development I use python from Homebrew. I have installed `lxml` package via `pip install lxml`.

The question is how to install `lxml` package into a user-specified directory using system built-in python?

Comment: What is workflow directory? Also what is Alfred? :)

Comment: I mean is this question specific to Alfred or are you in general looking for a way to install and include a Python package into a user-specified folder?

Comment: @jsalonen I'm looking for general solution. [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) is popular productivity app and it's mentioned just as an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Python packages into per-user folder with `--user` switch. For example:

```
pip install lxml --user
```

If this is not sufficient, you can use `--root` and specify target directly complete by hand. For instance if your module or whatever is located at `/module1` you can install the package under it with:

```
pip install lxml --root /module1
```

This results in `lxml` getting installed under `/module1/Python27/Lib/site-packages/lxml` folder.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you wan't to install lxml system-wide (where default Python is located). You can try finding where the system-wide Python interpreter stores it's packages.

Try typing this in terminal:

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
```

That will tell you where you should install your desired package (lxml).

Comment: I understood he specifically doesn't want to use system-wide install location. Good tip anyways!

Comment: I want to install package into a user-specified folder.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem installing pip into system python:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo /usr/bin/python get-pip.py
```

Pip installed to directory: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip`

Then you can install packages using sudo:

`sudo pip install lxml`

And you get something like this:

```
/usr/bin/python -c 'import lxml; print(lxml.get_include())'
['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/includes', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libxml', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libxslt', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libexslt']`
```